# pl/sql ,oracle add heading in cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqlplus

how I can add heading for table shown at top , in my code like this pic:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUy9M.png)

```
declare 
E_Name employ.name%type; 
E_Salary employ.salary%type; 
CURSOR c_employees is 
SELECT name , salary  from employ order by salary desc; 
BEGIN 
OPEN c_employees; 
LOOP 
FETCH c_employees into E_Name,E_Salary ; 
EXIT WHEN c_employees%notfound;
dbms_output.put_line( rpad(E_Name, 20, '.') || ' ' || rpad('$', (E_Salary/100), '$')||'      '||E_Salary); 
END LOOP; 
CLOSE c_employees;
END; 
/
```

Answer (score 2):

Include two more `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`s which will display that header (lines #2 and 3).

For example (using my tables as I don't have yours):

```
SQL> begin
  2    dbms_output.put_line('Emloyee name    Salary');
  3    dbms_output.put_line('------------    ------');
  4
  5    for cur_r in (select ename, sal from emp where deptno = 10) loop
  6      dbms_output.put_line(rpad(cur_r.ename, 12, ' ') ||'    '||
  7                           to_char(cur_r.sal, '99990'));
  8    end loop;
  9  end;
 10  /
Emloyee name    Salary
------------    ------
CLARK             2450
KING              5000
MILLER            1300

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```